# save div as png - html2canvas - blurry quality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html2canvas

Using html2canvas i'm trying to capture a div and save it as a .png file, and it works!

*(just using window.open in example to simplify it - same quality problem)*

However the image sharpness / quality of the images inside the targeted div is pretty bad. I'm not quite sure how to improve the image quality/sharpness. Any suggestions ?

**saveAsPNG function:**

```
saveAsPNG = function(id) {
var target = document.getElementById(id);

  html2canvas(target, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
      window.open(data);     
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: First of all, `image/png` is useless because it's the default value for `toDataURL`. And the `encoderOptions` (2nd parameter) is only used for `image/jpeg` and `image/webp`. It does not solve the problem but it "corrects" the code.

Comment: I added this line `document.body.appendChild(canvas);` before the on with `toDataURL`. And the canvas rendering is blurry also. So it comes from html2canvas and there's not option in it to improve quality.

Comment: Also, I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31726736/5119765

Comment: okay, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

What does html2canvas is not "actually" taking a screenshot but making representation. So it builds the screenshot **based on the information available on the page.**

Maybe an option not to take blurry images is to use it.

https://github.com/ivoviz/feedback

This is a jQuery plugin based on html2canvas, which allows you to take screenshots to a certain part of the page. Give it a try :)