# How to increase the resolution of the image while converting from canvas.todataURL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, canvas, html2canvas

The image is captured from a DIV using HTML2CANVAS, but the image quality is very poor and it pixalets. The captured image resolution is 96 dpi, how to increase the resolution ?

Is there any way to get a good quality image with high resolution, please help me out.

My Code :

```
 <div style="border-style: solid; height: 15cm; width: 15cm; border-radius:25px; 
             position: relative; top: 1px;" id="DIV1">

var element = $("#DIV1");

html2canvas(element, {
  useCORS: true,
  onrendered: function (canvas) {

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        window.open(dataURL);
      }
   });
```

I am placing the image above the DIV1 using FileUploader which is a high resolution image, but when html2canvas captures the image, the image pixalets and resolution will be 96dpi. How to increase the resolution to 300 dpi ?

Answer (score 2):

The standard Windows display dpi is 96 dpi so it makes sense that a straight screen capture without some form of up-scaling will result in an image with a similar dpi.

There is a feature request logged at the [html2canvas GitHub repository](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/241) for exactly this type of capability however it has been open since 2013. One workaround is to first scale the element using `transform: scale(2, 2)` however it's not ideal.

Comment: i have used this feature, it just cut my image proportionally. http://i.stack.imgur.com/0amrZ.png

Comment: Post the parts of the HTML and CSS you are having trouble with.

Comment: I don't think CSS3 transforms are supported by html2canvas. But you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36858051/1009901) to achieve high resolution with html2canvas. The trick is to provide your own canvas to html2canvas, and get 2d context and scale that before doing html2canvas.