# html2canvas images getting blurred

Tags: javascript, html, image, plotly, html2canvas

I'm using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to convert a `div` containing graph ( graphs are being generated by [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/) ) to image, so it can be downloaded. But the graph is getting blurred in the image.

This my code :

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById('graph_div')], {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        location.href = data;
    }
});
```

I've seen [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sq7hg/2/) and these images are rendering just fine so I don't think this might be a retina display issue as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22819006/5437621)

This is the actual div ( grey color is because of an overlaying div ) : [image]

And this is the image html2canvas is generating :[image]

Can you guys please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It looks like the numbers are rendered twice, but why only the numbers I don't know.

Comment: `I don't think this might be a retina display issue` are you on a retina display?

Comment: No, not on retina display

Comment: then that can't be the issue :p

Comment: `a div containing graph` - how is this graph created?

Comment: i'm using plotly ( https://plot.ly/javascript/ )

Comment: theoretisch is right. The numbers are being rendered in two different fonts (or font sizes). My guess is that it's originally rendered like that, but one of the copies of the text isn't visible for some reason. But I don't know enough about image formats to say anything more.

Comment: Why don't you use plotly's download as image function?

Comment: I don't want the user to use other options available in plotify ( like zoom into a particular section, save image to cloud,  and other options...specially the made with plotify message :P ), so I decided to remove the entire options panel, overlay graph with a transparent div and give just an option to download the graph